unity : instantiate create two object at once
I found that there were others who had similar problems, but none of those solutions helped me. My Instantiate function seems to create two instance at once, but I could not figure out why. This is my code:
public GameObject GetCard(CardInfo c)
{
    Debug.Log("GetCard call!");
    var temp = Instantiate(cardBackground);
    Debug.Log("between");
    temp.GetComponent<Card>().SetCardInfo(c);
    Debug.Log("GetCard return!");
    return temp;
}

Inside card script:
void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("Card is generated! " + GetInstanceID());
}

void Start()
{
    if (cardInfo != null)
        SetCardInfo(cardInfo);
    else
        Debug.Log("cardInfo is null");
}

and this is my output:
GetCard call!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
DeckManager:GetCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Singletons/DeckManager.cs:132)
Deck:AddCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:57)
Deck:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:19)

Card is generated! -4400
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Card:Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Card.cs:31)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate<UnityEngine.GameObject> (UnityEngine.GameObject)
DeckManager:GetCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Singletons/DeckManager.cs:133)
Deck:AddCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:57)
Deck:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:19)

Card is generated! -4420
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Card:Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Card.cs:31)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate<UnityEngine.GameObject> (UnityEngine.GameObject)
DeckManager:GetCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Singletons/DeckManager.cs:133)
Deck:AddCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:57)
Deck:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:19)

between
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
DeckManager:GetCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Singletons/DeckManager.cs:134)
Deck:AddCard (CardInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:57)
Deck:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Deck.cs:19)

I have no idea why this is happening. Any explanations would help me so much.

I guess there are 2 card scripts attached on this cardBackground.

I swear I checked every components of cardBackground like 10 times, and now I just found second card script attached to it. I must have been insane. Thank you.

If you spawn these gameobjects based on input (mouse, keyboard), check if they double fire.
